# Changing the Return-path using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Is there a way to change the return-path using PHPMailer

I did the following and it did not work

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader('Return-path:test@email.co.za');
```

I'm using the following statement to send mails

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

    } else {
        //Building the reporting email to report on all the mails send 
        echo "Message REPORT sent!\n";
    }
```

I get the email but the return path does not change?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following solved the issue, I adjusted the Sender property and it worked for me. `$mail->Sender = 'test@email.co.za';`

Comment: Right, that works. That sets the Return-Path internally. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

the correct way to set returnpath (as of july 2013) is by using:

```
$mail->ReturnPath='bounce_here@domain.com';
```

the phpmailer source contains the following, which is why I think $mail->Sender worked

```
if ($this->ReturnPath) {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', '<'.trim($this->ReturnPath).'>');
} elseif ($this->Sender == '') {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', '<'.trim($this->From).'>');
} else {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', '<'.trim($this->Sender).'>');
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer instead.

Comment: This is no longer the case, as phpmailer expains in it's code: 
/**
     * The Return-Path of the message.
     * If empty, it will be set to either From or Sender.
     * var string
     * deprecated Email senders should never set a return-path header;
     * it's the receiver's job (RFC5321 section 4.4), so this no longer does anything.
     * link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.4 RFC5321 reference
     */

Comment: Hello. I do not understand why ? every emailing solution (mailchimp...) set return path to user VERP adresses for tracking bounces ...we cannot do that with phpamiler ? ??? why ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$mail->Sender = 'noreply@domain.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for this is that the mail server you’re sending this mail over enforces a specific return path. This is often the case for “hosted” webspace.

In that case, you don’t have a lot of options. Try talking to your hoster.

Answer (score 0):

We had problem with SPF validation althought DNS TXT entry was set. We found out that PHP Mailer sets Reaturn-Path autopamticaly by default in setFrom() method https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_setFrom See 3rd argument `auto` which in short does `$phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From`. But wordpress from unknown reason sets this 3rd param to false without any option to change it... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

`$phpmailer->setFrom( $from_email, $from_name, false );`

So we have created plugin with other benefits...

**wp-content/plugins/phpmailer-fixes/init.php**

```
/*
Plugin Name: PHPMailer Fixes
*/

// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/
// add_action( string $hook_name, callable $callback, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )

add_action('phpmailer_init', 'phpmailer_init_fixes', 99, 1);

function phpmailer_init_fixes($phpmailer) {
    // FIX 1: Fix not setting Return-Path and breaking SPF validation
    $phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From;

    // IMPROVEMENT 1: Remove default header: X-Mailer: PHPMailer X.Y.Z (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
    $phpmailer->XMailer = false;

    // IMPROVEMENT 2: Add DKIM signature (you must set DNS TXT entry)
    $phpmailer->DKIM_domain = 'example.com';
    $phpmailer->DKIM_selector = 'wordpress';
    $phpmailer->DKIM_private = '/path/to/dkim.private.key';
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using the Reply-path header, try this:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader('Reply-to:test@email.co.za');
```

I use the Reply-to header and have had great success even on shared spaces.

Comment: Did I misunderstand you? Are you wanting to change the path to which failed messages and warnings are sent to or are you wanting to change the address whereby people REPLY TO?

Comment: @webfac, if the mail is not delivered the email bounces back, I need to know to which address it bounces to and the only thing I think it bounces to is the reply-path

Comment: @Roland - That's correct yes, I misunderstood you for a moment. I see no reason why the Reply-path is not working, UNLESS this header is being placed BEFORE your standard To, From headers etc ?? If so taht may very well be the answer.

Comment: @webfac, I've managed to solve this I did the following $mail->Sender = 'test@email.co.za';

Comment: @Roland - Glad you sorted it out, that means that the class you're using has the function Sender in it which obviously applies the sender address to the From: AND Return-path header values. That's a strange way of doing it, I would prefer it if they gave you the option to implicitly set each header option yourself! Glad you nailed it though.

Comment: @webfac, I agree with you. At least we know now